# Создать переход с одного экрана на другой с загрузкой html в webview

Tags: android

Программа должна состоять из 2 экранов.

1 - Список тем

2 - webview

При нажатии на 1 экрана на одну из 8 тем, должен переходить на 2 экран и грузить нужную html.

Список как создать немного понял. Не понял как обработать нажатие на тему, и как грузить на 2 странице нужную мне html страницу.

Comment: Ваш вопрос сродни "Делаю операцию на сердце. Грудь вскрыл. Что делать не знаю." Покажите код. Расскажите - вы хотете отрывать в отдельной активити, либо просто подменяя view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если страницы находяться в Assets то так:

```
WebView myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView_id);
myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Если из инета, то так:

```
myBrowser.loadUrl("http://hashcode.ru");
```

При этом нужно в манифест добавить:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Так обработать нажатие на элемент списка:

```
>     ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
>     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View
> itemClicked,int position, long id) {
>     Intent intent = new Intent(List.this,WebView.class);
>     startActivity(intent);
>     }
>     });
```

Для передачи номера нажатого итема листвью:

> ```
> intent.putExtra("pos",position);
> ```

После во второй активности принимаем позицию:

```
int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos",0);
myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+pos.toString());
```

Вроде все!

Comment: Это я знаю, страница в assets. Надо чтобы при нажатии на 1 экране переходил на 2 и грузил html.

Тоесть, есть 2 экрана, 8 html страниц, и list на 8 кнопок.
При нажатии на 1 экране, на 1 кнопку, переходит на 2 экран и грузит 1.html
При нажатии на 1 экране, на 2 кнопку, переходит на 2 экран и грузит 2.html
и т.д.
Лист я создал, но не могу реализовать переход с загрузкой.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Создаете вторую Activity, на нее кидаете WebView, а переключение:
http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread642995.html
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/activity.php
да и вообще вот
[Google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83+activity&oq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83)